# loading external js library in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a javascript library using webpack

I added the file into my react application:

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Helmet>
       <script src="/static/lib.js"/>
    </Helmet>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

when I was checking the site sources - I found out that lib.js exists in there.
I have a component that needs to create an object that exists inside the lib.js file

```
#myComponent.js
class MyComponent extents Component {
    constructor(){
      this.obj = new MyObject() // here is the problem
    }
}
    render() {
       return <div className="main-background">
         some stuff
        </div>;
    }
}
```

I suspect that the problem has something to do with DomReady - the library probably doesn't get loaded and the module is not defined

Comment: At the top of your Component, try adding `/* global MyObject */` (also, *always* state the error message you're getting [and google it])

Comment: as I said I am getting an error saying that my object is not defined:
[build] src/components/myComponent/myComponent.js
  Line 12:25:  'MyObject' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution was to put my deploy the sdk project which I had into npm
and npm install it